# FOSRestBundle AccessDeniedException redirects to login page

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I use FOSRestBundle 2.1 with Symfony 3.0 for creating a RESTful JSON API, and I stuck with handling AccessDenied exception.
It redirects to the login page although I configured it to show a 403 error.

Controller:

```
/**
 * @RouteResource("User")
 */
class UsersController extends FOSRestController
{
    public function getAction($id)
    {
        throw $this->createAccessDeniedException();
    }
}
```

config.yml

```
fos_rest:
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    body_listener: true
    access_denied_listener:
        # all requests using the 'json' format will return a 403 on an access denied violation
        json: true
    format_listener: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
    exception:
        enabled: true
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Wed, 18 May 2016 20:06:48 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.1i mod_fcgid/2.3.9
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.13
Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
X-Debug-Token: 2f3cb8
X-Debug-Token-Link: http://localhost/app_dev.php/_profiler/2f3cb8
Location: http://localhost/app_dev.php/login
```

The issue persists with FOSRestBundle 2.0 but dissapears if rollback to 1.7 version.

Is that a bug of 2.0 branch or I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I am experiencing nearly same issue (apart from the redirect).

It appears Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ExceptionListener has a lower priority (0) than FOS\RestBundle\EventListener\AccessDeniedListener (5), thereby handleAuthenticationException() is called:

```
private function handleAuthenticationException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    ...

    try {
        $event->setResponse($this->startAuthentication($event->getRequest(), $exception));
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $event->setException($e);
    }
}
```

This will throw yet another auth exception in my application, but I am effectly being redirected and thus believe our issues to be the same.

Try to make your login protected behind a firwall as well, and you should see a nice json error. It will probably be a 500 error though, as the logic in FOSRESTs AccessDeniedListener will not be triggered.

You can fix the issue by creating a custom ExceptionController and essentially "re-do" the logic that was supposed to be handled by the AccessDeniedListener. There is a config parameter in FOSRest for this, or you can use a compiler pass.

```
# app/config/config.yml
fos_rest:
    exception:
        enabled: true
        exception_controller: 'Acme\DemoBundle\Controller\ExceptionController::showAction'
```

I added an issue on github https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/issues/1538

Answer (score 2):

So we waiting when they fix issue with priorities.
For now, here how you can change priority in dirty way:

#### yml

```
services:
    # temporary replacement for exception_listener before fix will be merged
    # https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/pull/1692
    fos_rest.exception_listener:
        class: App\ExceptionListener
        arguments: ['@monolog.logger']
```

#### Class

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

/**
 * Class ExceptionListener
 *
 * @package App\Extensions
 */
class ExceptionListener extends \FOS\RestBundle\EventListener\ExceptionListener
{
    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger = null)
    {
        parent::__construct('fos_rest.exception.twig_controller:showAction', $logger);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [KernelEvents::EXCEPTION => ['onKernelException', 3]];
    }
}
```